# Ternary operator doesn't allow iterative operator in it, but if-else does?

Tags: perl, foreach, ternary-operator

I noticed that if I replace the `if-else` statement I'm using with a ternary operator I end getting a compilation error when I try and run my code.  I believe the culprit is the `foreach()` loop I have inside my `if-else`. Do you know why the ternary operator isn't behaving the same as the if-else construct in this instance?

My code looks like this

```
#!/program/perl_v5.6.1/bin/perl5.6.1

use strict;
use warnings;


my $fruits_array_ref = &get_fruits();
if($fruits_array_ref != 0) {
    print("$_ is a fruit.\n") foreach(@$fruits_array_ref);
}
else {
    print("Maybe you like vegetables?\n");
}


sub get_fruits() {
    my @fruit_list;
    my $shopping_list = "/home/lr625/grocery_items";

    open(my $shopping_list_h, "<", $shopping_list) or die("Couldn't open.\n");
    while(my $line = <$shopping_list_h>) {
        next if $line =~ /^\#/;
        chomp($line);
        push(@fruit_list, $line);
    }
    close($shopping_list_h) or die("Couldn't close.\n");

    scalar(@fruit_list) > 0 ? return(\@fruit_list) : return(0);
}
```

My data in the grocery list looks like

```
# this is a header
# to my grocery list
apple
banana
grape
orange
```

I'm replacing the `if-else` with a `?:` operator to look like this now in the main function.

```
my $fruits_array_ref = &get_fruits();
$fruits_array_ref != 0 ? print("$_ is a fruit.\n") foreach(@$fruits_array_ref) : print("Maybe you like vegetables?\n");
```

Also, for reference my error says.

> syntax error at test.pl line 8, near ") foreach"
>
> Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your issue but if you're indeed using Perl 5.6.1 you should update to a new version, like 5.18 or 5.22 or whatever your OS offers. 5.6 is really, really old. However, I tried your code with 5.22.1 and got the same result.

Comment: I would, but I'm stuck with whatever work will give me. Gotta make do with what I got.

@choroba explained well that I was trying fit a control structure into being an operand in the ternary operator, so I might try out using `do`, or I'll stick with the predictable behavior of the `if-else`

Comment: You may want to take the time to absorb what Inferno is saying in his answer.  You seem to be in danger of approaching a "clever" solution, and, maintenance wise, "clever" is seldom a virtue.

Comment: Yeah, I did and I noticed that I had been working on a "clever" solution in my sub-function at the end I think.  Using my new knowledge, I think it would be better written as... `return( scalar(@fruit_list) > 0 ? \@fruit_list : 0 );`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`if-else` is a flow control structure, `?-:` is an operator that takes expressions as operands. `foreach` is a flow control structure, not an expression.

You can turn any block of code into an expression by using [do](http://p3rl.org/do):

```
$fruits_array_ref != 0
    ? do { print "$_ is a fruit.\n" for @$fruits_array_ref }
    : print "Maybe you like vegetables?\n";
```

But why?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers already pointed out that you can't use the ternary operator the way you tried. For the sake of completeness and to give you some sensible use cases, take a look at the following examples:

**#1: Used as a subroutine argument**

```
testSub($var eq 'test' ? 'foo' : 'bar');
```

Here you can see how the subroutine `testSub` is called with the argument `foo` if `$var` equals the string `test`. Otherwise `testSub` will be called with `bar`. This is useful because you cannot use an `if-else` structure as a sub argument.

**#2: Used for conditional assignment**

```
my $result = $var eq 'test' ? 'foo' : 'bar'; # $result will contain 'foo' or 'bar'
```

The ternary operator is not meant as a simple replacement to an `if-else` structure. Since it returns a value (here either `foo` or `bar`) it makes sense to also *use* this value. If you don't intend to use the returned value, you should go for the usual `if-else` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator takes *arguments* before `?` and `:`, see [in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator).  It can evaluate an expression and use its result for this. But a loop is not an expression and cannot 'run' inside.

For a demonstration -- you could, if you insisted, call a function which will as a side effect print

```
sub greet { say "hello" for 1..3 }

my $x = 1;
($x == 1) ? greet() : say "bye";
```

Actualy doing this in production code is a different matter and would likely be a bad idea. The whole point would be to rely entirely on side effects, opposite to what we normally want to do.

---

To explain my comment above -- the main point of the ternary operator is to *return a value*, with a choice between two values, in one statement.  While it is "equivalent" to an if-else, its use is (ideally) meant to be very different.  So doing some other processing inside the `?:` arguments, in any way, is really an abuse of notation, a side-effect, since they are intended to produce a value to be returned. Printing out of it is opposite to the idea of producing and returning a value.  This is not a criticism, the operator is used often and by many as a syntactic shortcut.

In this sense I would recommend to revert to an if-else for doing what is shown.

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` statement modifier can only be used at the end of a statement.

Why are you using `?:`?  You would normally only do that if you wanted a single result.

You could wrap the `print...foreach...` in a `do {...}`, or you could use `map` instead of `foreach`.  Or just leave it as an if/else.